# Is there a way to plot a gaussian curve in plotly (scaled to y-axix without normalizing it) without using distplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

[image]
I have been trying to plot a histogram fitted with a gaussian, the mean along with 1 sigma standard deviation errors. Using ff.create_distplot does not allow us to choose the range for the y axis we require, it automatically normalizes it. I have tried using the matplotlib version of things and tried making it work on plotly but without any avail.
My code is given below.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

**From the image you can see that the gaussian is normalized. How do I scale it to the y axis?**

```
GX= pd.read_csv(r'X.....X.


csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(GX, columns = ['ra','dec','rest','b_rest','B_rest','pmra','pmra_error','pmdec','pmdec_error','PM'])
ra = df['ra'].tolist()
dec = df['dec'].tolist()
rest = df['rest'].tolist()
b_rest = df['b_rest'].tolist()
B_rest = df['B_rest'].tolist()
pmra = df['pmra'].tolist()
pmra_E = df['pmra_error'].tolist()
pmdec = df['pmdec'].tolist()
pmdec_E = df['pmdec_error'].tolist()
PM = df['PM'].tolist() 
PM1 = []
c = 0
for i in range(len(PM)):
    if (PM[i]<100 and pmra[i]>-4.5 and pmra[i]<1.5 and pmdec[i]>1 and pmdec[i]<3):
        PM1.append(PM[i])
        c+=1
group_labels = ['Proper Motion']
color = ['#636EFA', '#EF553B', '#00CC96', '#AB63FA', '#FFA15A', '#19D3F3', '#FF6692', '#B6E880', '#FF97FF', '#FECB52']    
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(
        x = PM1
    )
)
mean = np.mean(PM1)
variance = np.var(PM1)
sigma = np.sqrt(PM1)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name = 'Gaussian',
        mode = 'lines',
        x = PM1,
        y = mlab.normpdf(PM1, mean, sigma)
    )
)
#Line Plot for mean
mean = np.mean(PM1)
stdev_pluss = mean + np.std(PM1)
stdev_minus = mean - np.std(PM1)
median = np.median(PM1)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name = 'Mean',
        x=[2.769491040712437]*1000,
        y = np.linspace(0,105,num = 1000),
        mode="lines",
        marker=dict(
            size=2,
            line=dict(
                color = 'rgb(128,177,211)',
                width=1
            )
        )
    )
)
#Line Plot for Median
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name = 'Median',
        x=[2.800431666]*1000,
        y = np.linspace(0,105,num = 1000),
        mode="lines",
        marker=dict(
            size=2,
            line=dict(
                color = 'rgb(128,177,211)',
                width=1
            )
        )
    )
)
#Plotting Standard Deviation Lines
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name = 'Stdev-',
        x=[(stdev_minus)]*1000,
        y = np.linspace(0,105,num = 1000),
        mode="lines",
        marker=dict(
            size=2,
            line=dict(
                color = 'rgb(128,177,211)',
                width=1
            )
        )
    )
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        name = 'Stdev+',
        x=[(stdev_pluss)]*1000,
        y = np.linspace(0,105,num = 1000),
        mode="lines",
        marker=dict(
            size=2,
            line=dict(
                color = 'rgb(128,177,211)',
                width=1
            )
        )
    )
)


fig.update_layout(
    title = 'Proper Motion Histogram + Gaussian distribution ',
    xaxis = dict(
        title='Proper Motion'
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        title='Count'
    ),
    template = 'plotly_dark',
    showlegend = True
)
fig.show()
print('Mean :{}\nMedian: {}\nStandard Deviation: {}'.format(mean,median,stdev))
```

Comment: So, what is it that you *would* like to display on the y-axis?

Comment: The histogram with a gaussian along with standard deviation and mean.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what do you want to have *on the y-axis*?

Comment: The count of my data. Here, i am trying to display the number of stars in the given range of Proper Motion values. I think this is what you're asking. Otherwise, i didn't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: So, is there a way this can be done? @vestland ?

Comment: Probably. I'll take a closer look when I find the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221465/discussion-between-astronerdf-and-vestland).